# php call variable and put back on while loop

Tags: php, output-buffering, ob-start

sorry for my last question where i try put some live code with ob_start buffer content is not helping me to solve my problem because buffer content just collects output text, it doesn't execute any code. thanks @akrys for your advices

what i want is to put code into while looping like this

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `users`"); 
$var = $row['full_name'];
include('test.php');
```

after i call test.php contain while code like:

```
while($row = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    echo $var;
}
```

everything is work if i replace **$var** with **$row['full_name'];**

but i get the name of row field from some script on index.php so i should access that file first then i call portable file contain query to fetch_array on test.php

how to make it work when i put it back with $var contain variable field name

thank you very much for your attention guys

Comment: You should define `$someVariable` before using it in a string. An output buffer just collects output text, it does't execute any code.

Comment: @akrys can you give a little example, because maybe I am wrong with the example i gave there,, in real case it's different.. but the first page i access is index.php and test.php only run an code when i need it..

Comment: and what i should use better than buffer to put content, thanks for you tell me now i knew buffer only run output not code

Comment: If your code is different, then show something that is equivalent to it.

Comment: @akrys i've checked my page process and it the same as what i mean on my question.. can you tell me what trick to replace ob buffer that can put the code like variables

Comment: What I see: your starting output buffering to create a string. (which should give a notice that someVariable is not defined, so this part is an empty string) Then you include a file which outputs the string you‘ve created. So you need to define your variables before the string is build.

Comment: Again: define variables *before* you use it. `$row` is unknown before the while loop starts. And which value do you expect in `$var`? The `full_name` column from the first, the second or even from the 1234th entry of your result set? The while loop is used to run through your result set and process every single row.

Answer (score 0):

you should to include before your code
page

test.php

```
<?php 
$someVariable = 'hello'; // the variable only can access in here
?>

<?php 
include('test.php');
ob_start();
echo "some text with call variable $someVariable";
echo "other stuff";
$tdcol1_val = ob_get_contents(); ob_clean();
echo $tdcol1_val; // 
?>
```

of course you can use define too

page test.php

```
<?php 
define( "SOMEVARIABLE", hello ); 
?>

<?php 
include('test.php');
ob_start();
echo "some text with call variable ".SOMEVARIABLE;
echo "other stuff";
$tdcol1_val = ob_get_contents(); ob_clean();
echo $tdcol1_val; // 
?>
```

Comment: sorry guys.. can i update this question ? i found that buffer content really not help me for this because buffer only work on string variable, i mean at my real code is working with sql while loop i want put $row query back on while loop.. so wait i try to update this question sorry...

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."
```

for more help, use the link below:

[enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Comment: sorry guys.. can i update this question ? i found that buffer content really not help me for this because buffer only work on string variable, i mean at my real code is working with sql while loop i want put $row query back on while loop.. so wait i try to update this question sorry...